# Error installing watir-classic

Tags: ruby, watir

Hi I tried to install the watir-classic but I got the following error

My system configurations
Windows 7

ruby 1.8.7

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing watir-classic:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    D:/Ruby_version/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for ffi.h... no
    checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
    checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... no
    checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... no
    checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no
    creating extconf.h
    creating Makefile

    nmake
   'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Did you also install the 1.8.7/1.9.3-specific [devkit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)?

Comment: @ orde ........yaa just now I downloaded it,what should I do with that now..I mean where should I extract the files and should I need to specify the path.

Comment: Extract it into a directory (e.g. C:\devkit).  Open a command prompt and cd to that directory.  Then run: `ruby dk.rb init` and `ruby dk.rb install`

Comment: hey I have ruby installed in my D directory still I need to install it in C directory or in the directory where ruby is present..........

Comment: Not sure.  Give the D:\ drive a shot.

Comment: no use still getting he same error .........

Comment: @Sampriti Panda Do u have any idea regarding these I even faced the same issue while creating the folder structure through Taza gem

Comment: @Justin Ko Any idea how to resolve,even i faced the same issue while creatign the folder structure for which we need to install taza gem